# Remove TF 2.0 Warning from printing

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I want to silent my code in order to delete TensorFlow:Warning from printing in the console.
I tried solutions founded on different blogs / even here.
Any permanent solution / idea to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t recommend it but you can suppress the warnings using the warning library in python

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```